# How to avoid doxygen's automatic folder based namespace?

Tags: file, namespaces, package, directory, doxygen

i am going crazy over this and i'm tired of searching - could someone please explain to me, how i can avoid the default namespace of doxygen, which seems to be the base input folder.

Here you can see what i mean: http://trac.sevo.org/doxyvb/html/_v_b6_module_8bas.html

The package "ClassicVB" is only named so, because it's the name of the folder in which this file is in. But is there any way to specify, to which package or namespace a specific file belongs?

You see, if i generate a documentation, i would like to state @namespace inside my .bas file and doxygen should then use this as the namespace of the included functions inside this file. But instead it is using the name of the folder, in which my .bas file is in.

Maybe i am just doing it wrong, but i spend the last couple of hours with this, i'm grateful for any help on this matter!

Answer (score 3):

I had to deal with the same and I managed this way. Go to Doxygen GUI:

> Expert->Project-> Set **FULL_PATH_NAMES** to **NO**

I think this will be enough. If not let me know. When you change something in Doxygen to not-default it becomes red, so I can quickly check all the boxes I have changed.

Comment: did this work for anybody? using doxygen 1.6 and it doesn't work. It still includes the tmp folder i exported my code to as the namespace. I have a wrapper script and the extracted code is put into a temp dir like `/tmp/4j38hsdk/<python_source_files>`